# Visual Studio Code Intelisense falsely errors when using sequelize get method using Typescript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, sequelize.js

I have a model in Sequelize :

```
export class Opportunity extends Model {
  @IsUUID(4)
  @PrimaryKey
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
  })
  opportunityId: string;

  @ForeignKey(() => AccountContact)
  @Column({
    type: DataType.UUID,
   })
   accountContactId: string;
        
   @BelongsTo(() => AccountContact)
   accountContact: AccountContact;
}
```

Which I use in the following way:

```
const opportunityObject: Opportunity = await OpportunityService.getById(Id);
const accountContact = opportunityObject.getAccountContact();
```

Visual Studio Code falsely indicates that the method getAccountContact does not exists in type Opportunity even though Sequelize creates it on the fly and it works.

Does anyone know of a way to make Visual Studio Code to honor the get methods that are created on-the-fly? Because some file names are falsely colored in red, I can't tell the difference between the true and false errors

I know that I can use Eager Loading, but in this specific case, it will not be suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

After some more digging I found this post: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-typescript#type-safe-usage-of-auto-generated-functions that suggests the following:

> With the creation of a relation, sequelize generates some method on
> the corresponding models. So when you create a 1:n relation between
> ModelA and ModelB, an instance of ModelA will have the functions
> getModelBs, setModelBs, addModelB, removeModelB, hasModelB. These
> functions still exist with sequelize-typescript. But TypeScript wont
> recognize them and will complain if you try to access getModelB,
> setModelB or addModelB. To make TypeScript happy, the Model.prototype
> of sequelize-typescript has $set, $get, $add functions.

Comment: remember to mark this as accepted if this was a satisfactory answer for yourself